# get the keycode value - javascript

Tags: javascript, web, onkeypress

I am trying to get the pressed key value but ... no result or it outputs "undefined".
Here's the code:

```
    <body onkeypress="checkLetter(e)" >
    </body>

    <script>
        function checkLetter(e)
        {
            var mot = "aracnophobie";
            var lettre = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            alert(lettre);
        }
    </script>
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: What's the reason of assigning `onclick` event to the `body`?

Comment: I am making a "hangman" game and when the user press a key I have to check if the letter is contained in the word. So I assign the `onkeypress` event to body to be sure it will detect the user input

Comment: you assign onclick not onkeypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about you're trying to do, but test it with an "event" param, not "e" : onclick="checkLetter(event)"